# How to create a feature module with lazy loading in Ionic 6

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

I created a hello world Ionic 6 Angular Project.

In the root folder I use

`ng generate module customers --route customers --module app.module`

This command I know from angular to create a lazy loaded feauter Module.

But I got  this Error Message.

`File customers/customers.module.ts does not exist.`

If I create a module with this name first, I got the Error Message something like "there is already a customer.module.ts, merge conflict".

How to generate a lazy loaded feature module, using the cli command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the ionic command

```
ionic generate
```

than I choosed "Page". This create everything with module and lazy loading support.